# What is Azure's Equivalent of Google Cloud's Service Accounts

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm coming from Google Cloud Platform, and have been used to creating service agents, essentially user accounts to grant permissions/access that I specify to non human actors, so they can view/modify resources/attributes. I have been exploring Azure all evening and can't quite find something similar to that. Can anyone suggest Azure services or keywords I should do some reading on so I figure out how to implement similar identity and access in Azure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to start off by looking at Azure Active Directory Service Principals and Application Registrations. These are the rough equivalent to Service Accounts. You'll also want to research Managed Service Identities, which are a way to simplify the use of Applications and Service Principals. You can [start with this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals) and keep linking from there.

Comment: Wonderful, this looks like just what I needed. From what I've read so far, I went on to create a new application of type: "Web app / API" in Active Directory.
With [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal) can you confirm I'm going in the right direction?

Comment: @WillNjundong Yes, you're going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This [medium article](https://rav3n.medium.com/drop-the-bastion-in-the-clouds-aws-azure-kinda-and-gcp-e589df7d4fec) can give you a good comparison  circa 2020.